# How to prove that this minimizing sequence is bounded? (paper by Rabinowitz)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $n\ge 2$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ bounded and containing $0$. Define
$$E=\left\lbrace q\in W^{1, 2}([0, +\infty), \mathbb{R}^n) : \int_0^\infty |\dot{q}(t)|^2 dt <\infty\right\rbrace.$$
It is known that $E$ is an Hilbert space if endowed with the norm
$$\|q\|^2 = \int_0^\infty |\dot{q}(t)|^2 dt +|q(0)|^2.$$
Let $V\in C^1(\overline{\Omega}, \mathbb{R})$ with $V(x) < V(0)=0$ for all $x\in\overline{\Omega}\setminus\{0\}$. Let also $\Gamma\subset E$ be defined as
$$\Gamma = \left\lbrace q\in E: q(0)\in\partial\Omega, \ q(\infty)=0 , \ q(t)\in\overline{\Omega} \text{ for all } t\in [0, +\infty)\right\rbrace$$
and for $q\in\Gamma$ consider the functional
$$I(q) = \frac12\int_0^\infty |\dot{q}(t)|^2 dt - \int_0^\infty V(q) dt.$$
Let $$c=\inf_{q\in\Gamma} I(q).$$

I am trying to understand to understand the following sentence from this paper by Rabinowitz

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02571356

which reads as: Let $(q_m)$ be a minimizing sequence for the functional. Since $V\le 0$ and $\overline{\Omega}$ is compact, the form of $I$ shows that $(q_m)$ is bounded in $E$.

Could anyone please help me to understand why the minimizing sequence is bounded in $E$? I have tried assuming by contradiction that it is not bounded, but I do not know how to properly use the information that $V\le 0$ and $\overline{\Omega}$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Omega$ is bounded, we directly have $\vert q_m(0) \vert < C$ for some $C>0$ and for all $m$.

Moreover, since $V\leq 0$, $I(q)\geq \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \vert \dot{q}(t)\vert dt$ for any $q\in \Gamma$. Because $(q_m)$ is a minimizing sequence, $I(q_m)\to c$ and so $(I(q_m))_m$ is bounded.

Adding those two estimates, $\Vert q_m\Vert \leq 2I(q_m) + C \leq C'$ for some $C'>0$, hence the boundedness.